# why this code is not create a file in html5

Tags: html

i want to create a 'abc.txt' file in the folder where the .html file exist. in html5.
i tri with this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>title</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function onInitFs(fs) {
fs.root.getFile('abc.txt', {create: true, exclusive: true}, function(fileEntry) {
}, errorHandler);
}
window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024*1024, onInitFs, errorHandler);
</script>
<input type="button" name="" id="" value="click" onclick="onInitFs(fs);"/>
</body>
</html>
```

But faild. Please tell me the correct method. (i tri with google chrome and letest firefox.)

Comment: change this 'abc.txt'to an absolute path like 'd:\abc.txt' and see if it works

Comment: i tri but not works.

Comment: What are the errors in the console?

Comment: i run the html in firefox. when i click the button then nothing happen.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/LocalFileSystem):

> The LocalFileSystem interface of the File System API gives you access to a **sandboxed** file system.

It doesn't give you access to the main filesystem for the computer. It is a virtual one created by the browser. You can only access files in it that you put there from your own code.